# Cannot PING between two network interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, routing, ping

I am playing around AWS EC2 instance and I came across a strange problem.

I created an EC2 instance (Instance A) with 2 network interfaces, and the following is the routing table:

```
default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 
default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth1  metric 10001 
169.254.169.254 dev eth0 
172.31.32.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.42.99 
172.31.32.0/20 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.47.72
```

Now I try to ping from interface eth0 to eth1 using the command:`ping -I eth0 172.31.47.72`, but it did not work. Then I use tcpdump to listen to icmp traffic on eth0 and get the following results:

```
23:52:05.741380 IP ip-172-31-42-99 > ip-172-31-47-72: ICMP echo request, id 26033, seq 1, length 64
23:52:06.772710 IP ip-172-31-42-99 > ip-172-31-47-72: ICMP echo request, id 26033, seq 2, length 64
23:52:07.796705 IP ip-172-31-42-99 > ip-172-31-47-72: ICMP echo request, id 26033, seq 3, length 64
23:52:08.820704 IP ip-172-31-42-99 > ip-172-31-47-72: ICMP echo request, id 26033, seq 4, length 64
23:52:09.844704 IP ip-172-31-42-99 > ip-172-31-47-72: ICMP echo request, id 26033, seq 5, length 64
```

which seem eth1 received ICMP request but no response received by eth0. And when I tried to ping from eth1 to eth0, similar failure happened. My iptables rule was set default by ACCEPT all traffics.

---Debug 1 : Do self Ping---

```
ping -I eth0 172.31.42.99
ping -I eth1 172.31.47.72
```

Both worked!!!

---Debug 2: Create another instance within the same subnet---

I created another EC2 instance (Instance B) with the private IP of 172.31.42.86. Ping Instance B from Instance A through both interfaces:

```
ping -I eth0 172.31.42.86
ping -I eth1 172.31.42.86
```

Both worked!!!

Ping both interfaces of Instance A from Instance B:

```
ping 172.31.42.99
ping 172.31.47.72
```

Both worked!!!

Any one has some ideas about why?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to ping from one interface to another?

If you want to test them **create a separate instance** and ping them both from there.

Remember that VPC network is not your usual ethernet segment but instead a routed network with one segment per device. It may sometimes be difficult to play tricks such as these  that would normally work on a switched network.

Comment: I just wonder if there is a way to do this, e.g. by editing some routing rules. Because I think eth1 can receive ICMP request, but eth0 cannot receive ICMP response. It is kind of like to be filtered, just my guess...

Comment: @chengzx So the icmp packets leave eth0. Do they arrive to eth1? Check with tcpdump. Do the replies go back out from eth1? Do they arrive to eth0? Figure out up to which point it works and where it breaks.

Comment: The above is all the tcpdump result when I run ```tcpdump -i eth0 icmp```, I can only see eth0 send ICMP echo request to eth1, then nothing else